# CircleCI build all commits between last

Tags: circleci

I am pushing a PR on a project, and the build fails.
I know that the master branch works.

How do I tell circleCI to build all the commits in-between so that I see which change broke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. If you push one commit at a time, CircleCI will build each one. If you push multiple commits at once though, it will only build the head commit.

We do have a feature request open for this, which can "heart" to add your support: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/manually-trigger-a-build-all-commits-between-two-revisions/10160

---

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Yes I was suspecting this as well. I am the person who opened the feature request btw :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I didn't think to compare the usernames. Well this answer and link on Stack Overflow is useful for future people who find this. :)